# Achieve Inter-App Communication on iOS through sockets

Tags: ios, sockets, background-process

I am wondering how to do Inter-App Communication on iOS in iOS 7. It occurred to me that if I was the foreground app I could bind to sockets and act like a server, and if I was the background app (and had a background entitlement like audio) then I can connect to servers. So it seemed to me like it would be possible to do Inter-App Communication by agreeing on a port between 2 apps and simply switching which app binds to a port based on whether it is in the foreground or not.

Problem is, I can never seem to connect to localhost from the background, for example I have this code on a loop:

```
truct addrinfo *server_address;
int ret = getaddrinfo("localhost", "1666", NULL, &server_address);
int connection_id = connect(self.socketHandle, server_address->ai_addr, server_address->ai_addrlen);
```

And connection_id is always -1. I am unsure why I cannot connect given the bind process does not throw any errors.

Answer (score 0):

Check this answer: [iOS - Is it possible to communicate between apps via localhost?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13734248/ios-is-it-possible-to-communicate-between-apps-via-localhost)

Also, remember to make sure that you're background app is not stopped when the other app is entering in the foreground (by default the app will be stopped)

But generally speaking I don't think it's the good way to do interapp communication: the 'spirit' of iOS is to generally have only one app running in the foreground. So why do you need to communicate with a background app? I am quite sure that you can find a better way to achieve your result.

Comment: You imply there *is* a good way for apps to communicate. What would it/they be?